# create elasticsearch index every min

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create an elasticsearch index every minute with the below PUT statement.

```
PUT /%3Ctest-logs-%25%7B%2BYYYY-MM-dd_hh%3Amm%7D%3E
{
  "aliases": {
    "test-logs_write_new": {}
  }
}
```

which when decoded translates to `/<test-logs-%{+YYYY-MM-dd_hh:mm}>`

however i am getting the below parsing error

```
{
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse date field [+YYYY-MM-dd_hh:mm] with format [uuuu.MM.dd]: [failed to parse date field [+YYYY-MM-dd_hh:mm] with format [uuuu.MM.dd]]"
      }
```

What am i missing? how do i resolve this? I am using ES/Kibana 7.6.2

Answer (score 0):

The correct date pattern would be this one: `+yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH:mm`

So,

```
PUT /%3Ctest-logs-%25%7B%2Byyyy-MM-dd%27_%27HH%3Amm%7D%3E
{
  "aliases": {
    "test-logs_write_new": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error `"failed to parse date field [+yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm] with format [uuuu.MM.dd]: [failed to parse date field [+yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm] with format [uuuu.MM.dd]]"` I am using ES/Kibana 7.6.2.

Comment: You can't have `<`, `>` or `:` in an [index name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#indices-create-api-path-params), this could be messing up your request.

Comment: @leandrojmp it's perfectly ok, it's [the way to include](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html) date-math in index names

Comment: Actually, the `_` character is like the `T` in ISO8601, so we need to escape it with single quotes. See my updated answer